# Using headless pages in section lists in hugo

Tags: hugo

I've got a requirement to build a section page that is comprised of some static header material, static footer material, and several sections of user-managed content.  This user managed content is fragmentary, and as such should not have a permalink.

I thought that a good way to do this might be to use [headless pages](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-bundles/#headless-bundle).

It looks like to do that, these fragments must have a directory with an `index.md`, and should be accessible using the `.Site.GetPage` operator.

I'm struggling with figuring out how to use `.Site.GetPage` to get a list of pages to iterate over.  There will be 2..n user sections, and I don't want to rebuild the section's template if the number of content modules changes.

I'm assuming either there's some magic to query multiple pages using `.Site.GetPage`, or there's an entirely different operator for this.

That, or I've completely misunderstood how to use headless pages.

Here's my template for the section (`../layouts/the-range/section.html`):

```
{{ define "main" }}
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="halfhero" id="map"></div>
    </div>

    {{ $sections := .Site.GetPage "/the-range/*" }}
    <!-- leaf content at .../content/the-range/*/*.md -->
    {{ range $sections }}
    <section class="range-section">
        <div class="section-content">
            {{.Content}}
        </div>
        <img src="{{.Site.BaseURL}}{{.Params.images}}">
    </section>

    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

The headless content is just a series of markdown files as leaf bundles.

Answer (score 3):

Via the Hugo community at https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/using-headless-pages-in-section-lists-in-hugo/15275/2

Given a structure like this:

```
content/headless/
├── index.md     # headless = true in front matter
├── five.md
├── four
│   └── index.md
├── one
│   └── index.md
├── three
│   └── index.md
└── two
    └── index.md
```

You can do:

```
{{ $headlessbundle := .Site.GetPage "/headless" }}
{{ range ( $headlessbundle.Resources.ByType "page" ) }} <br>
  {{.}}
{{ end }}
```

Which should output:

```
Page(/headless/five.md) 
Page(/headless/four/index.md) 
Page(/headless/three/index.md) 
Page(/headless/two/index.md) 
Page(/headless/one/index.md)
```